# Modal view controller hides tab bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

In my tab based app, on clicking one of the tabs, I want to display a modal view controller with some info.
In my app delegate's didSelectViewController method, I am adding modal view. But it occupies entire screen and hides the tab bar. I don't want to hide the tab-bar, just want to display modal-view which pops up and can be dismissed.

How do I do it?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example if secondViewController is the second viewController for your second tabbar, you should do like this:

`[secondViewController.view addSubview:theViewYouWantToShow];`

Answer (score 6):

Modal view controllers are always presented full screen on an iPhone. If you don't want to hide the tab bar, then you need to present this view in some other way besides modal.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to "present" a new view controller, *over* another, *UNDER* the tab bar, by setting `modalPresentationStyle` to `.currentContext`.

```
let newViewController = UIViewController()
newViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
newViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
newViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.flipHorizontal
present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Edit: From more testing, the above can have some buggy behavior if someone changes the tab WHILE the `newViewController` is presented.

To "fix," I created a "switcher" - a `UIViewController` that animates between the view controllers that I want to flip UNDER the tab bar:

```
view.addSubview(nextView)
UIView.transition(from: currentView,
   to: nextView,
   duration: 0.5,
   options: animation,
   completion: { (_) in
      currentView.removeFromSuperview()
   })
```

In this case, `currentView` is the view of ViewControllerOne (the currently visible one), and the `nextView` is view of ViewControllerTwo (the one we want to present).

Answer (score 1):

In iOS , Modal View Controller is always have highest priority in all view controllers available. So you can not use Modal View Controller in your case.

If you just want to show popup on the screen with back ground visibility, then just use **UIAlertView**. You can add OK or CANCEL button as per your requirement to remove alert view.

Or

If you want to show a full view with tab bar visibility, then add the view in a that tab as a subview. You can give it a feel like a pop up using **transform** property of a view.

Answer (score 1):

You can present it modally by setting PresentationStyle.This style presents viewController in a square and it does not occupy full screen.

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

You can also set the transition:

```
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```